# Use the form that I add an my project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

I added a form from another solution.(With right on my solution and clicked add existing item and then select a resent form with name "newForm.cs").Then this form with own objects added to my project.But I can't use this form in my code.For example I want to show this form.But it isn't in my solution as a class that I use:"newForm frm = new newForm".
How do I can add this form that I can use it as a class.
I hope I have made the correct question.
Thanks very much.

Comment: Why can't you use the form from your code? Do you get an error, or is it just not recognized by Intellisense? Have you tried rebuilding your project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to set this as startup form then Edit that from the program.cs file

Moreover might be you need to change the namespace of the added form, please check that.

If you want to start this form from other form then create an object of this form and show the instace of this form.

```
Formname frm1 = new Formname();
frm1.show();
```

Comment: @Bhavik Formname and formname are different

Comment: @Bhavik also there is no option as "Set this as Startup Form" instead there is a "Set as Startup Project" option for Project... well at least in my Visual studio Installation..

Comment: sorry about this.... so you can set the startup form from Program.cs and the Formname must be same at both the place, that is the name of the form you want  to show,,

Comment: @Bhavik yes now you got it right...you can edit your answer though

Comment: @Code Gray is he right about Context menu option... since u have edited it you should have corrected that too...

Comment: @Shekhar: Yeah, I know the context menu option doesn't exist. But that's a whole different answer, and I see this one was already accepted. I assumed he'd fix that himself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing this from some Already existing form then you simply create a new object of the Form like:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
//set other properties
frm.Show();
```

if you want it to be Startup form then in the Program.cs Change the Form in Application.Run to

```
Application.Run(new Form2());
```

**Update**

Ok i checked there can be Problem of different Namespaces of the Both forms. You may need to Manually or Search and Replace the Namespace name to that of the Project.. (usually its the name of the project.. check with other Forms of the Project).

OR you can include that Form's Namespace by use of `using` keyword in your code.